# query to get list of tables that has same columns from information_schema.columns?

Tags: database-design

idea is to list all the tables that has redundant columns across database using information_schema.columns!
let's say

table1 = dbo.ABC
columns = id, name, department, designation

table2= dbo.DEF
columns= department, permissions, cube

table3= dbo.GHI
columns= street, zip, city, state

the query should list the tables 'dbo.ABC'  and 'dbo.DEF'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
select distinct c1.table_schema||'.'||c1.table_name
from information_schema.columns c1
where exists (select 1
              from information_schema.columns c2
              where c2.table_name <> c1.table_name
                and c2.column_name = c1.column_name
                and c2.table_schema = c1.table_schema);
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. your query works but there is a slight change on the requirement. instead of jus listing, is there any way to compare each and every table in the data base and generate an additional column which will list the number of common column between each tables!! ?? please use join if possible thx. example:
(table1)ABC (table2)DEF (commonColumns)1